# How can I read the short lived parquet file from the url using pyspark?

Tags: azure, pyspark, databricks

How to read the parquet file (short lived parquet file) from the URL getting from Delta Sharing Rest Api in JSON response.

Tried with pandas, it is working fine.
But have to read using PySpark.

Comment: Add context, which file, url, is it on blob?

Comment: @Assaf Segev  Getting the Parquet url in the response body from API.... 
url = '{endpoints}/delta-sharing/shares/{share_name}/schemas/{schema_name}/tables/{table_name}/query'
headers = {'user-agent': 'my-app/0.0.1'}
response = requests.post(url, headers=headers)

print(response.text)